# Object Assignment vs Object Creation

Tags: oop, object, pointers

I have always found it hard to decide when I should create a single object and pass it to every object that needs it, or create a new object for every object which needs that item.

Some cases are so obvious, like **entity** objects which are **readonly** after allocation and instantiation. You can pass the same object anywhere and not worry about another object modifying it, which ruins the other objects holding a reference to it.

My problem mainly lies with objects that represent themselves to the user. Objects like `CCSprite` in cocos2d, `NSMenuItem` in Cocoa (AppKit) and other objects with visual representation..

---

#### Examples:

In **cocoa**, i know that I have to create an `NSMenu` for each `NSPopUpButton`, so that the selection for a specific button does not affect the rest. But, what about the `NSMenuItems` contained within? Can I create a single set and pass them to all the menus? What are your grounds, or how did you come to such a conclusion?

#### Other example:

In cocos2d, and almost all GUI based applications, you can pass to a button two images/sprites/...etc. such that one is for the normal state, and the other is for the selected (highlighted, pressed, clicked) state. Can I pass the same image/sprite/...etc. to both, making them point to the same object?

I hope this is not an implementation related issue (that it ultimately depends on the implementation) , since I face it in a lot of my programming projects, in cocoa, cocos2d, Java ... etc.

**PS: I need help with choosing the proper tags**

Comment: >_< I am coming to a conclusion that I must create new ones .. Since, most of these examples (NSMenuItem, CCSprite) have pointers to their parents .. Implying, they must belong to a single parent :'(

Comment: I guess it kind of depends. As you point out, if it's immutable you only need one. If it needs to know its parent, you've got to have one for each use (assuming user is parent). If you want everything that uses it to change at once, and I'd think images would fall into this category, you only want one. If the image moves, it's a toss up--if no one will notice the synchronization, you'll save memory and CPU by using one, but if they would you might want to go with separate instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest creating new instances unless doing this causes a performance problem. Sharing an `NSMenuItem` instance among many `NSMenu` makes it more difficulty to maintain control over that instance, which increases the risk of errors.

Comment: Thanks, but isn't your answer a bit too general? It doesn't really answer the question. I never worried about performance, I worried about writing and managing too many objects. And, I am not really worried about the risks, the problem is, does it even work properly?

Comment: Your question is very vague, so I can only give a general answer. The rule of thumb is to create as many instances as you need and to keep them limited scope. Besides, you need these objects for your application to work properly so why hold back on creating them?

Comment: Maintainability. That's it. By making a single object, I can change how it looks, and it'll update everywhere. This greatly enhances maintainability and reduces code cluttering. But, some objects that are *composed* of visual representatives tend to need that visual object to be for itself.

Comment: You seem to have decided how to proceed. I don't agree with the approach, but it's your design anyway :)